# Where the logging errors located in a django website

Tags: django, apache

I am a newbie in Django. I have a website created with Django + Apache. I imported logging module and print some intermediate values with logging error function. But I don't know where the logging file locates. The OS is Ubuntu.

I searched internet and could not find a good answer (Maybe I did not do it properly). Could someone tell me where can I find the logging file that contains the values I logged in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the Apache logs. Django errors are often logged to the webserver's log files.

Answer (score 0):

Keep this in your settings and the filename specifies the location of the file

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'file_userlogins': {                # define and name a handler
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler', # set the logging class to log to a file
        'formatter': 'verbose',         # define the formatter to associate
        'filename': os.path.join(VENV_ROOT, 'log', 'userlogins.log') # log file
    },
 'loggers': {
    'logview.userlogins': {              # define a logger - give it a name
        'handlers': ['file_userlogins'], # specify what handler to associate
        'level': 'INFO',                 # specify the logging level
        'propagate': True,
    },     
}       
}
```